# next.js Setting up ESLint for NextJs

Tags: reactjs, eslint, next.js

I have created basic next.js app using "npx create-next-app" and .eslintrc.json file created to add eslint rules.but it's not working.how to add linting rules to nextjs config

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "standard"
    ],
    "globals": {
        "Atomics": "readonly",
        "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly",
        "React": "writable"
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2018,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react"
    ],
    "rules": {
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off"
    }
}
```

I have tried this solution - https://medium.com/@joelmasters/setting-up-eslint-for-nextjs-37163d4cabaa

Answer (score 35, accepted):

#### Update

NextJS now has official guide to add eslint to project: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint
Additionally you need to install [ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint).

Also, If you're looking for ESLint with typescript support:  https://gourav.io/blog/nextjs-cheatsheet

#### Old answer:

Install ESLint

```
npm i eslint --save-dev
```

Install ESLint plugins:

```
npx install-peerdeps --dev eslint-config-airbnb
```

Above [single command](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb) will install 6 plugins: `eslint-config-airbnb`, `eslint-plugin-import`, `eslint-plugin-react`, `eslint-plugin-react-hooks`, and `eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y`. You can also install these plugins individually.

Install babel eslint

```
npm i -D babel-eslint
```

Install prettier plugin (optional, so that prettier doesn't mess up with linting)

```
 npm i -D eslint-config-prettier eslint-plugin-prettier
```

Your "devDependencies" should look something like this:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.20.2",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.2.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.20.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^2.5.1"
  }
```

Now, create a file `.eslintrc.json` at root of project.
Paste below config:

```
{
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "commonjs": true,
    "es6": true,
    "node": true
  },
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": [
    "eslint:recommended",
    "airbnb",
    "airbnb/hooks",
    "plugin:react/recommended",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:jsx-a11y/recommended",
    // "plugin:react-hooks/recommended",
    // always put prettier at last
    "prettier"
  ],
  "globals": {
    "Atomics": "readonly",
    "SharedArrayBuffer": "readonly"
  },
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true // enable linting for jsx files
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 11,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "settings": {
    "react": {
      "version": "detect"
    }
  },
  "plugins": ["react", "react-hooks"],
  "rules": {
    // NextJs specific fix: suppress errors for missing 'import React' in files for nextjs
    "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
   // NextJs specific fix: allow jsx syntax in js files
    "react/jsx-filename-extension": [1, { "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"] }], //should add ".ts" if typescript project
    "react/display-name": 1
  }
}
```

Also, install [ESLint extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=dbaeumer.vscode-eslint) for VSCode.

*Reload VSCode window once to get proper linting*

ESLint will automatically start detecting errors/warnings in `*.js` and `*.jsx` files. If that's not the case then either your project has no linting errors or ESLint is not properly setup.
To test if linting works run eslint command in terminal with folder path i.e. `eslint pages/**` and notice output.

To disable linting of some files/folders you can create a `.eslintignore` at the root of project.

`.eslintignore`:

```
# don't ever lint node_modules
node_modules
# don't lint build output (make sure it's set to your correct build folder name)
dist
# don't lint nyc coverage output
coverage
```

Finally, you can also add linting to `scripts` in `package.json` as a part of your build/deploy process:

```
"scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint ./components/** ./pages/** -c .eslintrc.json --ext js,jsx",
    "lint-fix": "eslint ./components/** ./pages/** -c .eslintrc.json --fix --ext js,jsx",
}
```

See my current ESLint configuration for `NextJS` Typescript project: https://github.com/GorvGoyl/Personal-Site-Gourav.io/blob/main/.eslintrc.js

Comment: I followed your steps for the Next.js/React install. How I run eslint now? `npm run lint`?

Comment: linting should automatically work in background after restarting vscode. you can also manually lint: `eslint src/\*\*` for linting files under `src` directory or else add this command to package.json.

Comment: what do you mean manually? where would I run that? `eslint src/\*\*`. I restarted my vscode but don't see any linter errors. I imported a react hook and didn't use it but don't see an error telling me that

Comment: by manually i meant adding it to npm scripts as a part of build/deploy process. To test if linting is setup you can manually run eslint command in terminal and it will give output. regarding hooks, it should throw error so make sure you have added eslint plugins properly.

Comment: i changed my script to this and it still doesn’t work `"lint": "eslint src/\*\* ./components/** ./pages/** -c .eslintrc.json --ext js,jsx"`
` then i ran `npm run lint`

Comment: great, thanks a lot. Only one litte issue, remove the `,` (comma) behind  `SharedArrayBuffer` in your `.eslintrc.json`

Answer (score 15):

you need to install required npm modules.

with Npm:

```
npm i -D babel-eslint eslint-config-airbnb eslint eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks
```

with Yarn:

```
yarn add -D babel-eslint eslint-config-airbnb eslint eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y eslint-plugin-import eslint-plugin-react eslint-plugin-react-hooks
```

Here is related article about that

https://medium.com/@melih193/next-js-eslint-setup-tutorial-for-airbnb-config-c2b04183a92a

Comment: Note that, If you have installed **Eslint** successfully, but got no bug report from Eslint like you expected, then you might have forgot to **initialize Eslint**. To do that, run this command from the root of your project `./node_modules/.bin/eslint --init`

Answer (score 1):

**Official in-tree examples**

As [mentioned by GorvGoyl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61160352/895245), some better integration was added around Next.js 11.

Although there is documentation at: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint being a eslint newbie I just couldn't understand what I was supposed to do, so I just looked under examples/ and found some actual working code:

**examples/with-eslint**

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/v12.0.7/examples/with-eslint

Minimal eslint example.

The setup contains:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "with-eslint",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "^7.24.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7"
  }
}
```

.eslintrc

```
{
  "extends": "next",
  "root": true
}
```

pages/index.js

```
const Home = () => (
  <div>
    <script src="https://fake-script.com" />
    <p>Home</p>
  </div>
)

export default Home
```

For example doing:

```
cd examples/with-eslint
npm install
npm run lint
```

gives the desired error:

> 3:5  Warning: External synchronous scripts are forbidden. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-sync-scripts.  @next/next/no-sync-scripts

We can modify pages/index.js a bit to add some more cases that we might want to fail:

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  let s = 'abc'
  s = "abc"
  let unused
  if (false) {
    React.useEffect(() => 1)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <script src="https://fake-script.com" />
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

and the results are:

- `"` vs `'` on strings: unchecked
- `unused` unused variable: unchecked
- conditional `React.useEffect`: checked. I think this is because it includes the `'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',` at: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/v12.0.7/packages/eslint-config-next/index.js#L12

**examples/with-typescript-eslint-jest**

https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/v12.0.7/examples/with-typescript-eslint-jest

Exmple also with typescript.

Note that this example cannot be run in-tree otherwise it fails with:

> ESLint couldn't find the plugin "eslint-plugin-jest".

which is must be picking up from repo toplevel:

> The plugin "eslint-plugin-jest" was referenced from the config file in "../../.eslintrc.json#overrides[0]".

you have to first copy it outside somewhere like:

```
cp -rv examples/with-typescript-eslint-jest /tmp
cd /tmp/with-typescript-eslint-jest
```

But I think this examples is a bit outdated as it is not using the"

```
  "extends": "next",
```

preset.

**My recommended Next 12 typescript + prettier setup**

Since the in-tree "examples/with-typescript-eslint-jest" doesn't look very up-to-date, here's a version of it that should be (just without jest):

package.json

```
{
  "name": "with-eslint",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "format": "prettier --ignore-path .gitignore --write .",
    "type-check": "tsc"
  },
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "install": "0.13.0",
    "next": "12.0.7",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "12.12.21",
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "eslint": "8.5.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "12.0.7",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "7.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "typescript": "4.5.4"
  },
  "prettier": {
    "printWidth": 80,
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
  }
}
```

.eslintrc.json

```
{
  "extends": ["eslint:recommended", "next", "prettier"],
  "plugins": ["prettier"],
  "rules": {
    "prettier/prettier": "error"
  }
}
```

tsconfig.json (autogenerated by Next when you run `npm run dev`)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "incremental": true
  },
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

.gitignore

```
# See https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/ for more about ignoring files.

# dependencies
/node_modules
/.pnp
.pnp.js

# testing
/coverage

# next.js
/.next/
/out/

# production
/build

# misc
.DS_Store
*.pem

# debug
npm-debug.log*
yarn-debug.log*
yarn-error.log*

# local env files
.env.local
.env.development.local
.env.test.local
.env.production.local

# vercel
.vercel

# typescript
*.tsbuildinfo
```

pages/index.tsx

```
import React from 'react'

const Home = () => {
  let n: number
  let s = 'abc'
  s = "abc"
  let unused
  if (false) {
    React.useEffect(() => 1)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <script src="https://fake-script.com" />
      <p>Home</p>
    </div>
  )
}

export default Home
```

With this setup doing:

```
npm run lint
```

catches all issues as we would like:

```
4:7  Error: 'n' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
6:3  Error: 's' is assigned a value but never used.  no-unused-vars
6:7  Error: Replace `"abc"` with `'abc'`  prettier/prettier
7:7  Error: 'unused' is defined but never used.  no-unused-vars
8:7  Error: Unexpected constant condition.  no-constant-condition
9:5  Error: React Hook "React.useEffect" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
13:7  Warning: External synchronous scripts are forbidden. See: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/no-sync-scripts.  @next/next/no-sync-scripts
```

The prettier errors can be fixed automatically with autoformatting:

```
npm run format
```

which automatically patches for us:

```
--- a/pages/index.tsx
+++ b/pages/index.tsx
@@ -3,7 +3,7 @@ import React from 'react'
 const Home = () => {
   let n: number
   let s = 'abc'
-  s = "abc"
+  s = 'abc'
   let unused
   if (false) {
```

Running:

```
npm run type-check
```

catches the type error:

```
pages/index.tsx:9:27 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'void | Destructor'.

9     React.useEffect(() => 1)
```

Both `npm run lint` and `npm run type-check` are automatically run by `npm run build`.

**Lint is enabled only on `pages/`, `components/` and `lib/` by default**

As mentioned at: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/eslint#linting-custom-directories-and-files

To enable it everywhere in the projects:

```
module.exports = {
  eslint: {
    dirs: ['.'],
  },
}
```